# how i can pull out custom template in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one column like this in SQL Server and I need get this codes

```
## Title##
حساب-س1-2564492-305-151ساير سپرده ها

حساب-س151.305.881307.1ساير سپرده ها 

حساب-س1-1547032-305-151ساير سپرده ها

حساب-س1-96658-305-651ساير سپرده ها

حساب-س1-7349772-305-751ساير سپرده ها

حساب-س2-96658-305-851ساير سپرده ها

حساب-س1-5545530-305-951ساير سپرده ها
```

How can I pull out the following data from this column?

This code has 1-2564492-305-151, 151.305.881307.1 titles

```
## Title##
1-2564492-305-151

151.305.881307.1 

1-1547032-305-151

1-96658-305-651

1-7349772-305-751

2-96658-305-851

1-5545530-305-951
```

I use this code but sometimes it doesn't work

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FindNumbers_Slash]
(
    @inputstring VARCHAR(100)
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    --declare variables---
    DECLARE @count1 SMALLINT
    DECLARE @len1 SMALLINT
    DECLARE @word VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @char1 CHAR
    --Assignment---
    SET @word = ''
    SET @count1 = 1
    SET @len1 = DATALENGTH(@inputstring)

    WHILE @count1 <= @len1
    BEGIN
        SET @char1 = SUBSTRING(@inputstring ,@count1 ,1)
        IF (@char1 BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
           OR @char1 = '/'
        BEGIN
            SET @word = @word + SUBSTRING(@inputstring ,@count1 ,1)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF RIGHT(@word ,1) <> '-'
               AND LEN(@word) <> 0
                SET @word = @word + '-'
        END

        SET @count1 = @count1 + 1
    END
    RETURN @word
END
```

This code is 85% OK but not 100%.

Comment: When doesn't it work?

Comment: when style has . insted -

151.305.881307.1

Comment: Please edit your question and show the initial column data with the resulting data for the scenario which fails.

Comment: would it be better to simply put this data into separate columns in the first place, then you don't have this parsing problem when you try to retrieve it. If it's possible to change the database design, that's probably an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the language `substring()` doesn't work properly. When I reverse it and apply the `substring()` it worked.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('FindNumbers_Slash_V2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[FindNumbers_Slash_V2];
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FindNumbers_Slash_V2]
(
    @InputString    NVARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Word   NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @Word = SUBSTRING(@InputString
                        ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@InputString)
                        ,LEN(@InputString)+1    - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@InputString)
                        )

SET @Word = REVERSE(@Word)
SET @Word = SUBSTRING(@Word
                        ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Word)
                        ,LEN(@Word)+1   - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Word)
                        )

RETURN REVERSE(@Word)
END
```

Comment: thank you so much, same record is revers

Answer (score 0):

I used `PATINDEX` to match against the first and last number in the input string and then used `SUBSTRING` to extract the numeric part

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @first int;
DECLARE @last int;

SET @input ='حساب-س1-96658-305-651ساير سپرده ها'
SET @first = PATINDEX( '%[0-9]%',@input);
SET @last = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@input));

SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@input, @first, LEN(@input));
SELECT SUBSTRING(@temp, 1, @last + 2)
```

This outputs `1-96658-305-651` in my client so you might have to do REVERSE on the result since I am a little confused on how my client handles Arabic characters. Hopefully though this will get you close enough to figure out tha last details yourself